# ChartJs line chart time cartesian axis number of ticks and wierd offset

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to make a chart to show data for the last 7 days.
My x axis - is a time cartesian axis and time unit is set to 'day' but the chart shows me only 6 ticks and I want to show 7 ticks, one tick for every day.

Also the ticks are offset to the chart points, I want the points be exactly align with the ticks

```js
let [priceData, scoreData] = generateFakeData(7);

    // max price to show on the chart is max price + 1000
    const maxPrice = Math.max(...priceData.map(data => data.y)) + 1000;

    //console.log(data);
    console.log(priceData[0].x);
    console.log(priceData[scoreData.length - 1].x);

    function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    }

    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      pointRadius: 0,
      options: {
        elements: {
          point: {
            pointRadius: 0,
            pointHoverRadius: 3
          }
        },
        interaction: {
          mode: 'nearest',
          intersect: false,
          axis: 'x'
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              // This more specific font property overrides the global property
              color: '#fff',
              font: {
                size: 14,
              }
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'time',
            beginAtZero: true,
            ticks: {
              color: "white",
              autoSkip: false,
              maxTicksLimit: 7,
              count: 7,
            },
            time: {
              displayFormats: {
                month: 'dd MMM yy'
              },

              unit: 'day'
            },
            gridLines: {
              offsetGridLines: true,
            },
            offset: false,
          },
          y: {
            type: 'linear',
            min: 0,
            max: maxPrice,
            ticks: {
              color: "white"
            }
          },
          y1: {
            type: 'linear',
            min: 0.5,
            max: 10.5,
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            ticks: {
              color: "white",
              autoSkip: false,
              maxTicksLimit: 12,
              callback: function (val, index) {
                // Hide first and last tick label
                return val === 0.5 || val === 10.5 ? '' : this.getLabelForValue(val);
              },
            },
            // grid line settings
            grid: {
              drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
            },
          },
        }
      },
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'price',
            data: priceData,
            borderColor: [
              '#ffb800'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
            label: 'score',
            data: scoreData,
            borderColor: [
              '#00ff00'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            yAxisID: 'y1',
          }
        ]
      }
    });

    function generateFakeData(numOfDays) {
      const priceData = [];
      const scoreData = [];
      let today = new Date();
      priceData.unshift({ x: new Date(today), y: generateRandomNumber(1000, 2500) });
      scoreData.unshift({ x: new Date(today), y: generateRandomNumber(1, 10) });
      for (let i = 0; i < numOfDays - 1; i++) {
        const newDate = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
        priceData.unshift({ x: new Date(newDate), y: generateRandomNumber(1000, 2500) });
        scoreData.unshift({ x: new Date(newDate), y: generateRandomNumber(1, 10) });
      }
      return [priceData, scoreData];
    }
```

```css
html {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Link to jsBin: https://jsbin.com/viduman/5/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to set the hour of each day to (0,0,0,0)

```
let today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```